# Inserting undertilde in Chapter title

Tags: symbols, chapters

I'm using undertilde package in amsbook document class.

I want to insert `$\utilde{\times}$` in chapter title.

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `\protect` before the command:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{undertilde}
\begin{document}

\chapter{I want to insert $\protect\utilde{\times}$ in chapter title}
foo
\end{document}
```